How to convolve two signals of different sample rates and lengths?
I have two spectra (one is an aperiodic signal and the other is a transfer function) and I would like to multiply these in the frequency domain, followed by an IFFT to calculate the expected output waveform. However, the signal and transfer function are sampled at different rates and have different lengths, so I need to manipulate the data to ensure frequency bins align before I can carry out the multiplication - I would like to know the best way to do this.
What I have tried:
Linear interpolation in the frequency domain
This causes problems. For example, a sin wave becomes a damped sin as a result of this sort of interpolation.
Upsampling in the frequency domain
Adding zeros between datapoints. This seems to produce relatively good results, however because you have to add an integer number of zeros between all datapoints this only produces my desired result in a very limited set of situations (ratio of sample rates between the two spectra is an integer).
Zero padding the shorter signal in the time domain
I believe this also requires the sample time of the shorter signal to be a perfect factor of the sample time of the longer signal in order for the frequency bins to perfectly align by doing it this way.
Other options I have not yet tried:
Sinc interpolation in the frequency domain
This is supposedly equivalent to zero padding in the time domain, but seems quite involved to implement, so I have not attempted it yet.
Interpolation and zero padding in the time domain
This seems like it could be the optimum solution.
Before going further I thought I would try asking Stack Exchange to see if there is a better way that I have not yet thought of. Thanks for any advice provided.
Edit: change of title and details as requested in comments:

Both signals start at zero in time
I am interested in developing a process that can be applied to many datasets, so no specific lengths other than the fact that they will likely be different
The events are one-time events i.e. there is no other relevant information outside of the window of data that has been captured


Zero padding in the time domain performs a sinc interpolation on your spectrum, so there’s no need to try sinc interpolation separately. Matching sample rates can be done with polyphase resampling. From there, appropriately zero-pad.

You want some flavor of sample rate conversion, or you may want to do an IFFT with overlap and add.  Please edit your question with detail: does one or the other of your time-domain samples start and end at zero?  What are the lengths?  What is the nature of your aperiodic real-world sample: is it continuous (i.e., a sample of a process that's longer than the process itself) or is it a capture of a one-time event?  Let us know these things, and we'll be armed with enough information to answer your question.

I recommend you retitle, "How to convolve two signals of different sampling rates"

Your best shot here is to resample one of the signals in the time domain. The safest would be to up-sample the signal with the smaller sample rate, but that depends on your specific details: how long are the signals, what's the spectral extension and what sample rate do you want/need your output to be.
Resampling or sample rate conversion is a well defined mathematical process and has been well researched. There are some subtleties to it which are important to understand in choosing the correct method. For example, take a look at https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/resample/Theory_Operation.html
Once both signals have the same sample rate, you convolve them using overlap add or overlap save methods. Direct multiplication in the frequency implements circular convolution (not linear convolution) which is probably not what you want.

Thank you for your answer. What would be the effect of circular convolution vs linear convolution? Would it produce a significantly different result?

Yes the answer would be significantly different.  Overlap add or Overlap save work by using circular convolution to implement linear convolution when processing the signal in finite sized consecutive blocks

Thanks for your comment @AndyWalls. I've read up on the effects of circular convolution. Would zero padding the end of the signal sufficiently far out not mitigate the effects of the circular convolution?

@Christian Yes. There is analytically a minimum amount of zero padding that one can add to make circular convolution equivalent to linear convolution, if you process the signals in one block large enough to only need one convolution.  In practice, on real time streaming signals, that is not useful, hence the development of the overlap save and overlap add methods.
